# Query Select Database MySQL showing songs with all Genres (Categories)

Tags: mysql, database

First of all, i'm not to good at english. So forgive me.

Here's my database

```
songs: id, songname, songpath, coverpath
genre : id, genrename
detail_genre : id, id_song, id_genre
```

There's example of my SONGS table content :

```
1, Kasbo - Aldrig Mer, songs/kasbo.mp3, cover/kasbo.jpg
2, Pamungkas - One Only, songs/oneonly.mp3, cover/oneonly.jpg
```

There's example of my GENRE table content :

```
1, Electronic Dance Music
2, Pop
3, Indie
```

There's example of my DETAIL_GENRE table content :

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 3
3, 2, 2
```

So, you can notice that every one song can have many genre.

I want to have SELECT query (songid, songname, songpath, coverpath, group of (id_genre), group of (genre_name)). So the result will be like this

```
1, Kasbo - Aldrig Mer, songs/kasbo.mp3, cover/kasbo.jpg, 1, Electronic Dance Music
2, Pamungkas - One Only, songs/oneonly.mp3, cover/oneonly.jpg, (2,3), (Pop, Indie)
```

Or maybe just (songid, songname, songpath, coverpath, group of (id_genre))

```
1, Kasbo - Aldrig Mer, songs/kasbo.mp3, cover/kasbo.jpg, 1
2, Pamungkas - One Only, songs/oneonly.mp3, cover/oneonly.jpg, (2,3)
```

I've tried to SELECT like this

```
SELECT * FROM detail_genre dg JOIN genre g ON dg.id_genre = g.id JOIN songs s ON dg.id_song = s.id GROUP BY g.id
```

But if some genre have many songs, it just will show first song that they've found.

Can help my guys to get the SELECT QUERY that i want? I'm a newbie. Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the joins from `songs` and use `LEFT` joins to the other tables, just in case a song does not have any genre (if all songs have genres change to `INNER` joins).
Then group by song and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to create comma separated lists for the genres:

```
SELECT s.id, s.songname, s.songpath, s.coverpath, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(g.id ORDER BY g.id) genre_ids,
       GROUP_CONCAT(g.genrename ORDER BY g.id) genre_names
FROM songs s
LEFT JOIN detail_genre dg ON dg.id_song = s.id 
LEFT JOIN genre g ON g.id = dg.id_genre
GROUP BY s.id, s.songname, s.songpath, s.coverpath
```

or aggregate first inside the join of `detail_genre` to `genre` and then join to `songs`:

```
SELECT s.id, s.songname, s.songpath, s.coverpath,
       t.genre_ids, t.genre_names
FROM songs s
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT dg.id_song, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(g.id ORDER BY g.id) genre_ids,
         GROUP_CONCAT(g.genrename ORDER BY g.id) genre_names
  FROM detail_genre dg INNER JOIN genre g 
  ON g.id = dg.id_genre
  GROUP BY dg.id_song
) t ON t.id_song = s.id
```

Comment: thanks, but it shown Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given

Comment: This is not a MySql error. The only typo i already corrected was a missing comma in the 2nd query.

Comment: hm i've tried your 2nd query, but the error is same

Comment: The error you get is a php error and has nothing to do with the queries in my answer.

Comment: yea, me too, i can't find your query mistakes. ok thankyou for your help bro, i will try it again